# How can I use the Kivy Filechooser to display server's files (remote computer)?

Tags: python, tcp, kivy, client-server, filechooser

I'm creating a client server program with the idea of a shared files cloud.
I want to add a screen which is displaying the server side files (to create a specific folder on the server which is the "cloud" and display it on the client's side, the client should be able to edit files, add files and open files).

Here is what I have for now (only the user's side is working).

--- Client ---

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder
import os
import socket
import sys


s = socket.socket()
PORT = 9898
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', PORT))


class P(FloatLayout):
    pass


def show_popup():
    show = P()
    popupWindow = Popup(title="", content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    popupWindow.open()


class UserFileManager(BoxLayout):
    def open(self, path, filename):
        try:
            os.startfile(filename[0])
        except:
            show_popup()


    def selected(self, filename):
        try:
            print ("selected: %s" % filename[0])
        except:
            pass


    def send(self, filename):
        s.send('SEND'.encode('utf-8'))
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            file_name_without_path = filename.split('\\')
            file_name_without_path = file_name_without_path[len(file_name_without_path)-1]
            s.send(file_name_without_path.encode('utf-8')) #send name
            filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
            s.send(str(filesize).encode('utf-8'))  # send size
            bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
            s.send(bytesToSend)
            bytes_sent = 0
            while len(bytesToSend) != 0:
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                bytes_sent += len(bytesToSend)
                s.send(bytesToSend)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return UserFileManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
    # Close the connection from client side
    s.close()
```

---- my.kv file ----

```
<RoundedButton@Button>:
    background_color : (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    back_color : (1,0,1,1)
    border_radius: [18]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.back_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius



<UserFileManager>:
    id: my_widget
    GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            Label:
                text: "Welcome To RonDrive"
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            size: root.width, root.height - 100
            FileChooserListView:
                id: filechooser
                on_selection: my_widget.selected(filechooser.selection)
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2

            RoundedButton
                text: "open file"
                pos_hint: {"x":0.01, "top":1}
                back_color : (41/255, 21/255, 228/255, 1)
                size_hint: 0.1, 0.45
                on_release: my_widget.open(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
            RoundedButton
                text: " Upload File"
                pos_hint: {"x":0.115, "top":1}
                size_hint: 0.1, 0.45
                back_color : (41/255, 21/255, 228/255, 1)
                on_release: my_widget.send(filechooser.selection[0])

            RoundedButton
                text: "Nothing"
                size_hint: 0.1, 0.45
                pos_hint: {"x":0.01, "top":0.5}
                back_color : (41/255, 21/255, 228/255, 1)

<P>:
    Label:
        text: "You Haven't Chose Any File"
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top": 1}

    Button:
        text: "OK, Got It"
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y": 0.1}
```

--- server ---

```
import socket
import threading
import os


def UploadFile(client):
    filename = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    filesize = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    filesize = int(filesize)
    new_file_path = 'C:\\Users\\רון\\PycharmProjects\\untitled1\\RonDrive\\' + filename
    f = open(new_file_path, 'wb')
    data = client.recv(1024)
    totalRecv = len(data)
    f.write(data)
    while totalRecv < filesize:
        data = client.recv(1024)
        totalRecv += len(data)
        print(str((totalRecv / filesize) * 100) + "%")
        f.write(data)
    f.close()


def ReciveClientRequest(client):
    request = client.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")

    if request == "SEND":
        print ('UPLOAD')
        UploadFile(client)


def Main():
    host = '0.0.0.0'
    port = 9898

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(1)
    client, addr = s.accept()
    while True:
       ReciveClientRequest(client)

    s.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Does someone know?